# If websockets use a TCP connection is communication over them as slow as TCP?

Tags: tcp, websocket, udp, socket.io

From what I gather, Websockets use a TCP (or what amounts to TCP) connection for data transfer.  If this is the case, are messages traveling at TCP speeds?

Further complicating my understanding is Socket.IO which, in node, sometimes can initiate a Websocket connection using HTTP (by using express for instance).  When this happens is the websocket information being sent at HTTP speeds or something else?

Lastly, in node, I have an application that makes a UDP connection to the server, and then send the udp over the socket.io connection.  Is this UDP data being sent at the tcp speeds in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Who says TCP is slow?

Comment: It is *slower* than TCP due to the added overhead.

Comment: I never said slow, just slower than UDP

Comment: @Startec TCP is no slower at sending data than UDP.  There are a few packets' worth of connection setup and teardown cost, but other than that, the data flows just as fast for either form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSockets are a protocol upgrade within an HTTP connection (e.g. TCP) with its own framing - which means that it is a layer on top of TCP and due to its own framing it has even more overhead than TCP alone.

Apart from that, TCP packets by themselves are not slower than UDP packets and data transfer with a simple TCP connection can be faster than with a simple UDP connection, because flow control and reliable transfer is already integrated and you don't have to reinvent everything again (and often worse).

Comment: I see. I thought transmission via udp was almost always faster. since UDP doesn’t perform an arrival check, doesn't it require less bandwidth (with TCP you’ll generate a confirmation package in the reverse direction for each message that you send), and also, because it won’t wait for delayed messages like TCP isn't it speedier?

Comment: UDP is mostly used for protocols like RTP (audio+video transfer), where it is essential that packets arrive in a short time and it is ok if packets get lost. There UDP is faster, but at the (acceptable) cost of lost packets. But for reliable transport of data (where it is fatal if data get lost) one would need to add the flow control and detection and resubmission of lost packets, e.g reimplement what  TCP already offers. For normal connections the implementation TCP offers is optimal already, but it makes sense to create your own for special links (like high-latency satellite links).

Comment: So to break it all down in terms of speed: A websocket connection is a little slower than a "raw" TCP one, and TCP is a little slower than UDP (when it comes to real time transmission of data), but this comes at the cost of lost packets - right? Any notion of how much slower, specifically websocket speed vs. "raw" UDP? I am trying to use the transferred data to create audio-reactive visuals and can't afford too much latency.

Comment: For realtime audio/video where low latency is essential UDP is preferred. But, you need to use a codec which can deal with packet loss. If you need to transfer instead a complete audio/video file  as fast as possible (e.g. bandwidth usage and reliability needed, not low latency) you should use TCP together with a good codec, which does not need to deal with packet loss and  thus can offer better compression.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich is right - the impression that UDP is faster than TCP is only correct if you can afford to lose data.  UDP datagrams go as fast as the sender sends them, TCP segments go as fast as the receiver accepts them.  If your receiver can keep up, TCP can send just as fast as UDP.  If your receiver can't keep up, a TCP sender will slow down, but in UDP, you'll lose some of the data.